# Angular 6: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, custom-validators

I am practicing with Angular and I have a problem when I try to use "Build-in Validators". I try to pass as a parameter the value of a form field, but when I try to do it I simply have the error that I put in the title "Can not read property 'get' of undefined":

### form.component.ts

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
      'name': new FormControl(this.name, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(4),
        forbiddenNameValidator(this.name)
      ]),
      'alterEgo': new FormControl(this.alterEgo),
      'power': new FormControl(this.power, Validators.required)
    });
```

... more code ...

```
get name(): string { return this.form.get('name').value };
get power(): string { return this.form.get('power').value };
```

When I try to send the forbiddenNameValidator (this.name) method as a parameter, I get that error.

### form.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="Ver()">
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="name">Name</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" formControlName="name">
</div>
</form>
```

This is the error that I get:

[image]

Comment: why dont you give us your definition of `forbiddenNameValidator`?

Comment: `forbiddenNameValidator.bind(this)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `[formGroup]="form"` to your HTML form

```
<div class="form-group" [formGroup]="form">
   <label for="name">Name</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" formControlName="name">
</div>
```

Otherwise Angular won't know what to bind the form to, this is similar to `formControlName="name"` that you need to add for each control. The `form-group` class is purely used for styling.

Comment: I got the same error when I already had `[formGroup]="form"`, but was missing `form = this.fb.group(...)` in the TypeScript.